# SwiftUI - Hiding a ScrollView's indicators makes it stop scrolling

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to hide the indicators of a `ScrollView` but when I try doing so, the `ScrollView` just doesn't scroll anymore. I'm using macOS if that matters.

```swift
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    // Everything is in here
}
```

Comment: Looks like macOS only defect. On iOS & macCatalyst it works.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and kind of hoped that it would get fixed in the macOS 10.15.1 and Xcode 11.2. 
Since the content does not scroll anymore, what I have also seen is that it still has the bouncing effect on top (that too sometimes).

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  Works fine on iOS, but fails to work on macOS and macCatalyst.  @Asperi - you said it is working on macCatalyst - can you show your code?

Comment: @SoOverIt, see in answer.

Comment: This is fixed in Big Sur but still not in 10.15.7

Answer (score 1):

**On request of @SoOverIt**

Demo:

[image: demo]

Nothing special, just launched some other test example. Xcode 11.2 / macOS 10.15

```
var body : some View {

    VStack {
        ScrollView([.vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
            Group {
            Text("AAA")
            Text("BBB")
            Text("CCC")
            Text("DDD")
            Text("EEE")
            }
            Group {
            Text("AAA")
            Text("BBB")
            Text("CCC")
            Text("DDD")
            Text("EEE")
            }
            Group {
            Text("AAA")
            Text("BBB")
            Text("CCC")
            Text("DDD")
            Text("EEE")
            }
            Group {
            Text("AAA")
            Text("BBB")
            Text("CCC")
            Text("DDD")
            Text("EEE")
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
        .border(Color.blue)
    }
    .border(Color.red)
}
```

Comment: That's weird!   I did a copy and paste of your code into a new macCatalyst app - and still get scrolling errors.  I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and macOS 10.15.3.  I have memories of it working with previously - maybe it is borked on 11.3.1??  See answer below for video.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.

```swift
extension View {
    func hideIndicators() -> some View {
        return PanelScrollView{ self }
    }
}

struct PanelScrollView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        PanelScrollViewControllerRepresentable(content: self.content())
    }
}

struct PanelScrollViewControllerRepresentable<Content>: NSViewControllerRepresentable where Content: View{
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> PanelScrollViewHostingController<Content> {
        return PanelScrollViewHostingController(rootView: self.content)
    }

    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: PanelScrollViewHostingController<Content>, context: Context) {
    }

    typealias NSViewControllerType = PanelScrollViewHostingController<Content>

    let content: Content


}

class PanelScrollViewHostingController<Content>: NSHostingController<Content> where Content : View {

    var scrollView: NSScrollView?

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.scrollView = findNSScrollView(view: self.view)
        self.scrollView?.scrollerStyle = .overlay
        self.scrollView?.hasVerticalScroller = false
        self.scrollView?.hasHorizontalScroller = false
        super.viewDidAppear()
    }

    func findNSScrollView(view: NSView?) -> NSScrollView? {
        if view?.isKind(of: NSScrollView.self) ?? false {
            return (view as? NSScrollView)
        }

        for v in view?.subviews ?? [] {
            if let vc = findNSScrollView(view: v) {
                return vc
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Preview:

```
struct MyScrollView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack{
                Text("hello")
                Text("hello")
                Text("hello")
                Text("hello")
                Text("hello")
            }
        }.hideIndicators()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully they fix it soon, but this will work for now. I'm not going to think through this but just copy pasta, thanks!

Comment: Well, this fix has also caused me problems with @ObservedObject rerendering the View... Not sure what to do to prevent that.

Comment: @neptunes Same here... not updating the view anymore. Can not use this

Answer (score 0):

So... I think that's the only way for now.

You basically just put a `View` over your `ScrollView` indicator with the same `backgroundColor` as your background `View`

[image]

Note: This obviously only works if your background is static with no content at the trailing edge.

## Idea

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    
    let yourBackgroundColorLight: Color = .white
    let yourBackgroundColorDark: Color = .black

    var yourBackgroundColor: Color { colorScheme == .light ? yourBackgroundColorLight : yourBackgroundColorDark }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<1000) { i in
                    Text(String(i)).frame(width: 280).foregroundColor(.green)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(yourBackgroundColor) //<-- Same
        .overlay(
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(yourBackgroundColor) //<-- Same
            }
        )
    }
}
```

## Compact version

You could improve this like that, I suppose you have your color dynamically set up inside assets.

Usage:

```
ScrollView {
    ...
}
.hideIndicators(with: <#Your Color#>)
```

Implementation:

```
extension View {
    func hideIndicators(with color: Color) -> some View {
        return modifier(HideIndicators(color: color))
    }
}


struct HideIndicators: ViewModifier {
    let color: Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 10)
                        .foregroundColor(color)
                }
            )
    }
}
```